# Please can you point me to a Powershell, mouse tutorial

Tags: powershell

Please could somebody recommend a Powershell, mouse tutorial. I have been searching the internet but cannot find instructions on how to do then following.

I have data in a database which I want to select via a mouse. I have been able to display an output from the database in a Textbox, but cannot select it.

What I want to be able to do is select the line in the output and then use the information in that line.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I wouldn't recommend trying to tackle P/Invoking User32.dll to move the mouse to particular coordinates.  There are tons of conditions you'd have to account for (SSRS app bounds, knowing where the scroll window is in the app, etc.).  If you're just trying to read information from a SQL database, look at Invoke-SqlCmd

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Out-GridView -PassThru` on Windows to achieve this:

```
$selected = $datatable |Out-GridView -PassThru
```

Select the relevant line(s) by clicking (ctrl-click for more than one), and click `Ok` in the lower right corner.

`$selected` will then contain the relevant row(s)

Comment: I must've really misunderstood his ask.

Comment: @thepip3r I also understood it the other way around until I got to the "I have been able to display an output from the database in a Textbox" part

Comment: Thank you Mathias, that is sort of working, but I cannot select anything.

Comment: Thank you Mathias, that is sort of working, but I cannot select anything. The table is being displayed in the string part of the window but I cannot select anything individually. I think what is happening is that table is being displayed as a single item and you can only select the whole table. Displaying $selected does display the whole table. How do I break the table into its parts?

Comment: @martin Can you show us how you obtained the input? Please share the code you used if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here are some functions I use myself. I've tried to adapt them to how you will use it.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; 

function Mouse-signature-import(){
    $global:signature=@' 
      [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
'@ 

    $global:SendMouseClick = Add-Type -memberDefinition $global:signature -name "Win32MouseEventNew" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru 
}


function Mouse-Drag($from1,$from2,$to1,$to2){
    Mouse-signature-import

    [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$from1,$from2"
    $global:SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = "$to1,$to2"
    start-sleep -m 1500 # If we do not sleep, then the drag does not work right.
    $global:SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    write-host -f yellow -b black "Mouse-Drag" -nonewline; write-host -f Gray " from " -NoNewline; write-host -f Magenta "[" -nonewline; write-host -f Red "$from1 $from2" -nonewline;write-host -f Magenta "]" -nonewline; write-host -f Gray " to " -NoNewline; write-host -f Magenta "[" -nonewline; write-host -f Red "$to1 $to2" -nonewline; write-host -f Magenta "]";
}

function SendInput($a){

    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($a)

}

start-sleep -s 1 
Mouse-Drag 90 166 126 358
start-sleep -s 1
sendInput "^(c)"

$a = Get-Clipboard
$a
```

And to figure out the coordinates for where I want to move the mouse cursor to, I use this: `https://learn-powershell.net/2015/11/30/create-a-mouse-cursor-tracker-using-powershell-and-wpf/`

Basically what I'm doing above is moving the mouse to a cursor position, then I drag the mouse to position 2. Send a CTRL+C to copy what we have highlighted, then use get-clipboard to push the selected text into a variable ($a).

This method is not perfect for what you're trying to do, but it is how you want to do it so this is why I supplied my code. I would recommend trying to get the data through some other means as there is a lot that could go wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is returning a table from a function (RetriveData) that retrieves it from a database.

```
$listTable = RetriveData | Format-Table | Out-String

Write-host “$listTable”

$selected = $listTable | Out-GridView –PassThru

Write-host “$selected”
```

The write hosts are showing the table contents as I was expecting. The dialogue opened by Out-GridView shows the table highlighted in light blue, but seems to only be selectable as a complete table.
Am I using the `| Format-Table | Out-String` correctly here?

The code being used in the RetriveData function to return from the data base is.

```
$table = Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $databaseServer $databaseName –Query $sql
Return $table
```